# Scanner Class hasNextLine infinite loop

Tags: java, file, loops, input

why does this piece of code go into an infinite loop when I try to give it a basic text file?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
public class TestFile
{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
            // Read in input file                                                                                                                                            
            File input = new File(args[0]);
            Scanner freader = new Scanner(input);
            while (freader.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println("hi");
            }

            freader.close();

    }

}
```

The print line just keeps going.

Comment: (Why would it return false after it returned true?)

Comment: @Matt, please don't sign your posts. The flare added to your posts is your signature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `hasNexLine()` does neither get the line nor change the state of the scanner. if it's true once, and no other methods of the scanner are called, it'll always be true.

Answer (score 9):

Because you have to consume the nextLine so the code should be:

```
while ( theScanner.hasNextLine() ) {
    String theLine = theScanner.nextLine();
}
```

If you don't invoke `nextLine()` you will always be watching at the same line and it will always answer true to that.

Answer (score 4):

Add a call to `nextLine` or any other `Scanner` method that'll read in some input inside the `while` loop.

At the moment you're just repeatedly calling [hasNextLine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) (which **only** returns a `boolean`, it doesn't modify the stream) without retrieving any input from `freader`, so if `freader` initially has another line within its input `hasNextLine` will **always** return true and your loop is essentially `while (true)`.