# Java Scanner Standard in

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am using Eclipse as my IDE.  I am reading in a simple file:

```
1 Andrew
2 Peter
3 Andrew
3 Peter
3 Andrew
```

My problem is that sc.next() on the last line for Andrew hangs and never finishes. Is there a way to have it take in Andrew on the last line and then exit the while loop? I believe standard in is waiting for more input instead of just grabbing Andrew and saying i've got what i need and moves on.

Here is the part of the code that i am having trouble with

```
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){

             String number = sc.next();
             String name = sc.next();
             int numberI = Integer.parseInt(number);
             Usage usage = new Usage(name);
             computerNames[numberI].addObsseration(usage);

        }
        sc.close();
```

Thanks in advance to any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanner Class hasNextLine infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974238/scanner-class-hasnextline-infinite-loop)

Comment: If you don't invoke nextLine() you will always be watching at the same line and it will always answer true to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a big IO guy, but from what I remember in school (using C, not Java), often times we would put an escape at the end of a file (in your case, the last line could be "0 EOF") and then when number == 0 and name.equals("EOF"), you know to break out of the loop.

Edit: Jakob seems to have the appopriate to answer why this is happening tho.

Comment: Thanks I liked this option to add that at the end to signal the end of the file.

Comment: Glad I could help, I remember often times in a programming challenge, they would specify that the program continue to run so long as the input wasn't '0 0' or 'EOF'.

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem

You're using `hasNextLine()` mixed with `next()`. You should use `hasNext()` when you're grabbing data with `next()`. Additionally, you should know that you can combine the parsing of the integer into the same step by using `sc.nextInt()` instead of `sc.next()` to get an integer.

#### Why does this happen?

`sc.nextLine()` gobbles up everything until the next newline. `sc.next()` takes the next whitespace-separated token. `nextLine()` may have another newline available even though we've already captured all the tokens.

You may have to press Control+D after typing the input if you're not reading from a file but typing the data at the command line, to simulate the end of the file.

Comment: I had been trying both.  I get the same exact result from both.  Thank you for reinforcing what i thought was that hasnextline and nextline and hasnext and next should be together.  sorry the copy i threw up here was mismatched.  i was getting desperate!

Comment: you tried using the exact same code, but with `hasNext()` instead?

Comment: Yes i did.  and it still hangs on the last Andrew

Comment: You may have to press Control+D after typing the input if you're not reading from a file but typing the data at the command line, to simulate the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your Scanner is reading from standard in (`System.in`) rather than from your file (`/YourComputerPath/.../filename`). You need to change your instantiation of the scanner.

```
sc = new Scanner(new File("/PathToMyFile/.../myfile"));
```

Comment: Seems like he's using input redirection tho

Comment: I am using input redirection.  In eclipse you can set that in run config.  Also the program works it just hangs on the last part.  i can see that the first 4 lines work properly through the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading in input, not from a file, but from standard in. Because of this, unless you close the standard input stream into the running java process, the `Scanner` will always think that there is more input available.

If you do manage to close your standard input stream, your code will also fail if there is a trailing newline. You should use `hasNext()` instead of `hasNextLine()` to combat this problem.

If you want to read from a stream, I would recommend using a `BufferedReader` on an `InputStreamReader` with `readLine()` and `split()`. This will not only solve your problem but also make the input faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is often better to read a file, and parse it later (rather than at the same time). An example would be as such:

```
sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String input="";

while((input=sc.nextLine())!=null) {
  String[] arr=input.split(" ");
  int numberI=Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
  Usage usage=new Usage(arr[1]);
  computerNames[numberI].addObsseration(usage);
}
sc.close();
```

Comment: The problem with this is this still doesn't close the standard input. So it still hangs.  This would work in conjunction to the advice to add a 0 EOF as the last line.

Comment: Ah, very true. I didn't even look at the input. Nice catch, @user3352075